# Tests on a build agent fail because of missing EF6 tools (included in Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, mstest

We have TeamCity with 2 build agents:

- VM with Windows 8.1
- VM with Windows 10

Some of our projects use MS Build 12, others use MS Build 14. Some use MS Test 12, others use MS Test 14.

I installed the build tools for Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2015 on both machines. All builds were succesful, but our tests weren't.

Some of the projects configured with MSTest 2013 had failing tests on the Windows 10 VM and some of the projects configured with MSTest 2015 had failing tests on the Windows 8.1 VM.

The exception I get is the same for all the tests. This is the one I get on the Windows 8.1 VM:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The Entity Framework provider type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.
```

This is the exception I get on the Windows 10 VM:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The Entity Framework provider type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.
```

Everything worked fine on all of our development machines (some devs use VS 13, other devs use VS 15).

The problem was fixed on the Windows 10 VM by installing [Entity Framework 6 Tools for Visual Studio 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762).

As of now the Windows 8.1 VM has the tools for VS 2013 and the Windows 10 VM has the tools for VS 2013 and VS 2015.

As of Visual Studio 2015, the tools are included in the installation of Visual Studio itself. I'm not going to install VS on a build agent (the Windows 10 build agent is also a development machine, that is why it already has the tools installed)...

How can I get this to work on my Windows 8.1 VM, with or without installing the EF tools? Shouldn't installing the build tools be enough for a build agent?

Comment: I posted the same question on the [Entity Framework forum](http://forums.asp.net/p/2062689/5950520.aspx?p=True&t=635751543335606763).